# setting a form field if a table field is not empty

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$theinput = new inputSmartSearch($db,
    "chooseproduct", "Choose Product", $therecord["product"],
    "Choose Product", TRUE, NULL, NULL, TRUE, $required=true);
$theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
if(isset($therecord["product"]) || isset($therecord["cost"])) {
    $theinput->setAttribute("value",
        $therecord["product"] . ", " . $therecord["cost"]);
}
```

inputSmartSearch is a type of form field for a CMS system I am using.

What I am wanting to do to set the value of the form by default, as long as it is not empty, to avoid having the ", " be the default value.

```
var_dump($therecord["product"]);
```

shows string(0) "", so it is certainly empty.

Why then is ", " still being set as the default value of my form field?

Comment: Suppose the values are `false` or `""` (empty string), then `isset()` will eval to `true` but will print nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isset() checks if the variable is set and is not `NULL`, you need to check if it is empty. replace isset() with !empty() like this:

```
if (
    !empty($therecord["product"])||
    !empty($therecord["cost"])
) {
    $parts = array();
    if (!empty($therecord["product"])) {
        $parts[] = $therecord["product"];
    }
    if (!empty($therecord["cost"])) {
        $parts[] = $therecord["cost"];
    }
    $theinput->setAttribute("value", implode(', ', $parts));
}
```

EDIT: now puts comma only if needed

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
$myValue = ($therecord["product"]) ? $therecord["product"] . ", " . $therecord["cost"] : '';
$theinput->setAttribute("value",$myValue );
```

This will check if $therecord["product"] is empty and if it is, then make $myValue = '';

Yours would always print ", "; as there was nothing telling it not to.

You could also want one of the following:

```
if(isset($therecord["product"]) || isset($therecord["cost"])) {
    $myValue = '';
    if(!(empty($therecord["product"])) $myValue .= $therecord["product"].', ';
    if(!(empty($therecord["cost"])) $myValue .= $therecord["sot"];
    else $myValue = substr($myValue, 0, -2);
    $theinput->setAttribute("value", $myValue);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You have:

```
if(isset($therecord["product"]) || isset($therecord["cost"])) {
    $theinput->setAttribute("value",
        $therecord["product"] . ", " . $therecord["cost"]);
}
```

This says to me that if the variable $therecord["product"] or $therecord["cost"] exsits (even if empty) then set the value to be $therecord["product"], $therecord["cost"] so it could end up having any of the following outputs:

```
1) myprod, mycost
2) myprod,
3) , mycost
4) ,
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong above? Also won´t your solution set $myValue to $therecord["product"] if it isn´t empty, which isn´t what I want?

Comment: isset will check to see if var exists, what you may need is `empty` They will check if there is a value. _ I have updated my answer with another possible solution

Comment: I have updated again, with the explantion of your code at the bottom